# Can anyone help me to debug this code because it stopped working in the middle

Tags: c, gcc

Hello i just need to see why my Gcc stopped working after execution.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
static char *s[] = {"black", "white", "pink", "violet"};
char **ptr[] = {s+3, s+2, s+1, s}, ***p;
p=ptr;
++p;
printf("the value of **p is %s\n\t",**p); // printed on screen pink
printf("the value of **ptr[1] is %s\n\t",**ptr[1]); // here got the error
printf("the value of *(s[2]) is %s\n\t",*s[2]); // here got the error
return 0;
}
```

Comment: We cannot guess the many variations of what this question might mean. The `cmd` tag implies you are on Microsoft Windows. If that is not the case, please remove the `cmd` tag.

Comment: i don't know what you mean i just need to find the wrong thing on it.

Comment: @lit: If we cannot guess, how is it that two people did?

Comment: @EricPostpischil it's ok bro to me problem solved and really thanks for all

Comment: It's not clear to me what the problem actually is here. Did GCC stop working? Did you get a compiler error? Based on the answer, you seem to have had a bug in your code. Please [Edit] your question so that it is clear and useful to others in the future.

Comment: And since you haven't done so yet, take the [tour], read [Ask] and [MCVE]. It will save you loads of problems in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`**ptr[1]` is a `char`. You are passing it to `printf` for a `%s` conversion. `%s` requires a pointer to `char`, not a `char`. Pass `*ptr[1]` instead.

Similarly, instead of `*s[2]`, pass `s[2]`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer short and effective ^_^ ^_^

Comment: Can you please tell me if i put
printf("the value of *(s[2]) is %s\n\t",s[2]+1);

Comment: That should give you the string `"ink"`, since you're adding one to the pointer to the beginning of the string. I'd recommend running the code yourself and experimenting for questions like that. Experimentation is a good way to learn :)

Comment: @user9549915 first thanks bro, i just didn't get how it's work, when i see s[2] i said it will be pink if i add 1 to pink it's get confused to me and said it will be s[3] but i don't know the accessing of string element and how its done.

Comment: (hint: if you enable *compiler warnings*, e.g. `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` for `gcc`, then the compiler will tell you exactly what the problem is and on which line it can be found)

Comment: @MohammedKandeel: `s[2]` is a pointer to a `char`. When you add 1 to it, the result points to the next `char`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're referring to the segfault on the last two `printf`'s that you commented, you're dereferencing one time too many. `ptr` is an array of pointers to strings, but you dereference the second item twice, which gives a character. `s` is an array of strings, and dereferencing the third element also gives you a character. You can fix it by removing one `*` on each:

```
    printf("the value of *ptr[1] is %s\n\t", *ptr[1]);
    printf("the value of s[2] is %s\n\t", s[2]);
```

This gives the following output:

```
the value of **p is pink
    the value of *ptr[1] is pink
    the value of s[2] is pink
```

Comment: Thanks a lot i got it ^_^